# Post / page text (Callouts) that float 'next' to main paragraph text

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**What I'm trying to do:**

I want to create text that can "float around" other text; I believe *Callouts* are the term. Since I'm new to CSS, I don't know where to start. If someone could kick me in the right direction, I'm sure I can explore further (and dutifully log it here).

[image: My attempt to visualize what I'm trying to do]

**Additional thoughts:**

1. I'd like the 'highlight text' to still be a part of the narrative
   flow of the posts/pages (nothing trapped outside the content).
2. I don't even know if this is a CSS or PHP thingie.
3. As I've been trying to do everything via child theme, I haven't even investigated
   plugins. Is this wise?
4. A sample blog post is **[here](http://longgame.org/2011/08/parasites-and-agency/)**.

Many thanks, in advance, for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get things going with how I'm interpreting your request, you'd want to the following to your H5 tag:

- Float it (left or right)
- Specify a width
- Specify padding so items that are 'wrapping around it' aren't touching it

  h5 {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
      padding: 0 20px 20px 0; /* shorthand for: top, right, bottom, left */
  }

*(Tried to make an image to showcase this, but apparently my rep. isn't high enough to help that much ;)*

When you float things though, you take them out of the document's vertical flow, so depending on how this will be used you may want to investigate things like 'clearfix' or clearing a float if you need the height of the callout to be respected. (*Like if text isn't intended to wrap past the callout, your callout may overlap your footer or something odd like that.*)

I can elaborate further on a fix if you provide some more info. In your sample post, what would be a call out?

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I'm going to look into this asap. I was finding a lot about floating _images_ but not text. Still chipping away at my _green_-ness.